Bitcoin Core Inbound connections (TOR)
I downloaded Bitcoin Core and the synchronization is complete. I am in a double NAT situation (I don't have permission to alter the settings of one of the routers) so in order to receive inbound connections, I downloaded TOR. (I am using macOS and using homebrew) The problem is that my node doesn't have a proper inbound connection. I used my AWS EC2 ubuntu server to check the reachability of my onion address on my Macintosh using the command below and got a positive result. Still, my bitcoin node doesn't have any inbound connections. Can somebody help me?
$ torsocks nc -vz owdhrhanf7tfovhqckqi5qiuoe6pnm3py3kpkk257×333г47xgxdbiid.onion 8333
Connection to owdhrhanf7tfovhqckgi5qiuoe6pnm3py3kpkk257×333r47xgd5iid.onion 8333 port [tcp/*] succeeded!

$ bitcoin-cli getnetworkinfo
{
  "version": 270000,
  "subversion": "/Satoshi:27.0.0/",
  "protocolversion": 70016,
  "localservices": "0000000000000c09",
  "localservicesnames": [
    "NETWORK",
    "WITNESS",
    "NETWORK_LIMITED",
    "P2P_V2"
  ],
  "localrelay": true,
  "timeoffset": -1,
  "networkactive": true,
  "connections": 11,
  "connections_in": 1,
  "connections_out": 10,
  "networks": [
    {
      "name": "ipv4",
      "limited": true,
      "reachable": false,
      "proxy": "127.0.0.1:9050",
      "proxy_randomize_credentials": true
    },
    {
      "name": "ipv6",
      "limited": true,
      "reachable": false,
      "proxy": "127.0.0.1:9050",
      "proxy_randomize_credentials": true
    },
    {
      "name": "onion",
      "limited": false,
      "reachable": true,
      "proxy": "127.0.0.1:9050",
      "proxy_randomize_credentials": true
    },
    {
      "name": "i2p",
      "limited": true,
      "reachable": false,
      "proxy": "",
      "proxy_randomize_credentials": false
    },
    {
      "name": "cjdns",
      "limited": true,
      "reachable": false,
      "proxy": "127.0.0.1:9050",
      "proxy_randomize_credentials": true
    }
  ],
  "relayfee": 0.00001000,
  "incrementalfee": 0.00001000,
  "localaddresses": [
    {
      "address": "owdhrhanf7tfovhqckqi5qiuoe6pnm3py3kpkk257x333r47xgxd5iid.onion",
      "port": 8333,
      "score": 4
    }
  ],
  "warnings": ""
}

bitcoin.conf Connection options
onlynet=onion
listen=1
proxy=127.0.0.1:9050
bind=127.0.0.1
externalip=owdhrhanf7tfovhqckqi5qiuoe6pnm3py3kpkk257x333r47xgxd5iid.onion
natpmp=0
upnp=0

torrc
SOCKSPort 9050
ControlPort 9051

Log notice file /opt/homebrew/var/log/tor.log

CookieAuthentication 1
CookieAuthFile /opt/homebrew/var/lib/tor/control_auth_cookie

DataDirectory /opt/homebrew/var/lib/tor
HiddenServiceDir /opt/homebrew/var/lib/tor/BitcoinCore/
HiddenServicePort 8333 127.0.0.1:8333

At the time of this writing, there is one inbound connection, though which doesn't seem to be properly connected. (unroutable).
{
    "id": 47,
    "addr": "127.0.0.1:57728",
    "addrbind": "127.0.0.1:8333",
    "network": "not_publicly_routable",
    "services": "0000000000000000",
    "servicesnames": [
    ],
    "relaytxes": false,
    "lastsend": 1716916677,
    "lastrecv": 1716916678,
    "last_transaction": 0,
    "last_block": 0,
    "bytessent": 359,
    "bytesrecv": 296,
    "conntime": 1716916555,
    "timeoffset": -1,
    "pingtime": 1.487564,
    "minping": 1.205581,
    "version": 70016,
    "subver": "",
    "inbound": true,
    "bip152_hb_to": false,
    "bip152_hb_from": false,
    "startingheight": 0,
    "presynced_headers": -1,
    "synced_headers": -1,
    "synced_blocks": -1,
    "inflight": [
    ],
    "addr_relay_enabled": false,
    "addr_processed": 0,
    "addr_rate_limited": 0,
    "permissions": [
    ],
    "minfeefilter": 0.00000000,
    "bytessent_per_msg": {
      "feefilter": 32,
      "ping": 64,
      "pong": 32,
      "sendaddrv2": 24,
      "sendcmpct": 33,
      "verack": 24,
      "version": 126,
      "wtxidrelay": 24
    },
    "bytesrecv_per_msg": {
      "ping": 32,
      "pong": 64,
      "sendaddrv2": 24,
      "verack": 24,
      "version": 152
    },
    "connection_type": "inbound",
    "transport_protocol_type": "v1",
    "session_id": ""
  }

